# How to set a layout for JMenu?

Tags: java, swing

How can I make the each two of the menu items places next to each others (appearing to 2x2 grid) instead of having four of them one under the other?
When I run the program they appear all under each others

```
public class Paint_yara extends JApplet {
    public Paint_yara() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        JMenuItem newMI = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem openMI = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem saveMI = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem saveAsMI = new JMenuItem("Save as");
        fileMenu.add(newMI);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openMI);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveMI);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAsMI);
    }
}
```

Comment: A JMenu is not designed for this purpose. The items are added to a popup window and the layout is controlled by the LAF. The popup is designed to display vertically so that child menus can popup beside the popup. This is a well know user interface.

Comment: As much as I agree with @camickr, meaning, I don't think it is a good idea to change the look of a well known visual component, you *might* be able to change the layout of a JMenu using the 'setLayout' method.  Calling this method with some other type of LayoutManager.  That being said, you might have to also override the JMenu `add` and `addSeparator` methods to use the new layout manager you're setting.

Comment: @hooknc,  You can't change the layout of the JMenu, because the JMenu only displays the text (not the menu items). The components are NOT added to the JMenu. The "add(...)" method is overridden in JMenu. JMenu is not a container, like JPanel. The components added to the JMenu are saved and displayed in a popup window. `You can't just change the layout of the JMenu, (which the OP has already tried by using the GridLayout`). You need to get deeper into the UI to modify the popup window.